# Keyboard and brightness control not working: driver issue?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, keyboard, brightness

I have an *Acer Aspire 5680* PC, with *Windows 7 Ultimate*.

I have two main problems:

1. right- and down-arrow don't work, *i.e.*, when I press one of them nothing happens (but I don't think they are physically broken);
2. there is no way to access the brightness control, neither with *fn + right-arrow* nor by means of the display settings available in the control panel (the slider does not appear in the proper page of the control panel).

I don't have a deep understanding of the computer architecture, so my question is 
**how to proceed in order to fix these problems**.

I've already tried to re-install *Windows 7 Ultimate* with no success. I also tried to run Xubuntu on a live USB, and also there I found the same two problems.
If I enter the BIOS, also here the two arrows won't work. At this point I guess it could be a driver problem. Is this correct? Could instead be a problem not related to drivers? 
[edited after David's comment (see below)] If I connect to the computer an external USB keyboard, the arrows of the USB keyboard work properly, but *fn + right-arrow* is no longer a valid shortcut for increasing brightness level.

Thanks in advance to everyone would help me and excuse me for my English and for any mistake or omission I made writing the post (I'm a new user).

Comment: Have you tried a different (USB) keyboard?

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill for the suggestion. I connected a USB keyboard and now the arrows work properly. Does this mean it's a keyboard driver problem? In any case, in the USB keyboard there are no shortcuts of the type _fn + right-arrow_ to increase the brightness level, so the problem remains.

Comment: ***"Using an external USB keyboard, the arrows work properly..."*** So.. When you plug in the *USB keyboard;* the arrow keys on the *original keyboard* start working?

Comment: No, sorry for my english @tjt263, I didn't mean that. I wanted to say that by using an external USB keyboard I managed to use again all the arrows, but the key must be pressed in the USB keyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds more like a physical fault to me, with the original keyboard. After re-installing everything and the issue still exists, it is very likely to be a problem with the keys themselves.

If you are comfortable with removing the keyboard and cleaning it, that may help, as it could be that some alien matter has gotten itself in there, preventing the keys from functioning properly. ONLY DO THAT IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING!
Sorry for the caps, but that's kind of important :)

If the computer is under warranty then get them to sort it out for you.

If not, then you'll need to find someone who can take a look at it/fix it for you.

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In the last days I restored the computer to factory settings, but this didn't solve the problem with the keys, and unfortunately corroborates the hypothesis that the keys are physically broken. I also tried to remove and clean the keys, but nothing changed. 

As for the brightness problem, resetting the computer to the factory settings installed into the C: partition Windows XP. In this operating system I can control the brightness through the graphics card's settings. I then reinstalled Windows 7 into another partition but here the brightness control was missing.